# Force excel to refresh command ribbon (for office add-in) after updating manifest XML

Tags: xml, angular, ms-office, office-js

I'm sideloading an office add-in using office.js and an XML manifest located on a share drive. This adds a new ribbon to excel with a few custom command icons once the add-in is loaded.

However, **after editing the manifest.XML file, say I comment out a command icon from the ribbon, I have not figured out how to force a refresh of the excel ribbon to reflect my changes.**

**I've tried** reloading the add-in, re-adding it, restarting excel, updating the manifest version when saving, changing the manifest Id/GUID when saving, etc, but still have not been able to find a way to consistently update the ribbon immediately after making changes. It seems to just be loading a cached version of my manifest file. Any ideas?

**I'm on** Windows 10 using Excel 2016.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that it wasn't the ribbon that was caching old icons, it was actually the Office Add-ins window that was caching the old manifest files.

If you go to Insert -> My Add-ins -> Shared Folder
there is a refresh button in the top right corner which will refresh the manifest files to their latest changes.

[image: Refresh Icon in top right corner]

Comment: Is there any way I can do this programmatically? Somewhere in the file system where I can manually delete the 'My Add-ins' cache?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way that you can clear the cache for office:
delete the contents of this folder: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Wef\`

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache