# Is there any way to refresh the shared folder tab programmatically so that the user does not have to manually refresh the addin everytime

Tags: excel, office-js

I have a Office JS Excel addin with ribbon button and click of the button shows the tooltip. The tooltip data is stored in the manifest file. If I make any change in the manifest data, it is not reflected automatically in the Office application and even restart of the Office application does not help. The only workaround is to open Excel desktop app, and goto insert -> addins -> shared folder and then click on refresh.

Comment: Similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43852608/force-excel-to-refresh-command-ribbon-for-office-add-in-after-updating-manifes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force excel to refresh command ribbon (for office add-in) after updating manifest XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43852608/force-excel-to-refresh-command-ribbon-for-office-add-in-after-updating-manifes)

Comment: Hi Jerome, this does refreshes the manifest changes but is there any way to do it programmatically to give the user seamless experience. If any API that refreshes the ribbon frequently or just refreshes it on "Excel application start" would be great.